# Why is my Google Line Chart not displaying lines?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, google-visualization, coldfusion-8

I am looping through a datasource to grab data. The chart displays with the legend I want and the correct x and y axis but the lines do not display. Any thoughts on to why this is? Source code below:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <cfoutput>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
                        ['Date Worked',<cfloop query="name"> '#name#',</cfloop>],
                        <cfloop from="2012-12-18" to="2012-12-18" index="i">
                            <cfquery name="test" datasource="TrackPorter">
                                select  name, COALESCE(date_worked,'2012-12-18')date_worked, COALESCE(hours_worked,0)hours_worked 
                                from users 
                                left join records on  users.id = records.users_id and date_worked = '2012-12-18'
                                where active_pilot = 1 
                                order by date_worked asc 
                            </cfquery>
                            ['#test.date_worked#', #Valuelist(test.hours_worked)#]
                        </cfloop>
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: 'Test'
                    };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
        </cfoutput>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div
```

Here is the view source:

```
Here is the view source:




<html>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <h1>Pilot Timesheet</h1>
            <a href="excel_sheet_downloader.cfm"><button class="btn"       type="button" name="download_pilot_report">Download</button></a>
      <br />
      <br />
    <h1>Grapher</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
                    ['Date Worked', 'Keegan', 'Brady', 'Isaac', 'Christoph', 'Tyler',],

                        ['2012-12-18', 0.0,0.0,0.0,5.5,0.0]

                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Test'
                };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: if you view source the answer may appear more obvious when you look at the JavaScript. Can you post the generated JavaScript?

Comment: Here is the generated javascript when I view the source:

Comment: Sorry, view source is above ^^ in original question now

Comment: Have you checked if any errors in the JS console? (F12 in Chrome/Firefox).

Comment: just "closing script tag manually"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output needs to be in a format of

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
 ['Date Worked','2012-12-18'],
 ['Keegan',0],
 ['Brady',0],
 ['Isaac',0],
 ['Christoph',5.5],
 ['Tyler',0]
]);
```

You'll have to rework your output to correctly format the JavaScript

This isn't tested or complete, but this should help get you on the right track of output

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
 ['Date Worked',
 <cfset count = 0>
 <cfloop from="2012-12-18" to="2012-12-18" index="i">'#i#'<cfif count NEQ numberofloopsneeded (you need to calculate this)>,</cfif><cfset count++></cfloop>],
 <cfloop from="2012-12-18" to="2012-12-18" index="i">
   <cfquery name="test" datasource="TrackPorter">
   select  name, COALESCE(date_worked,'2012-12-18')date_worked, COALESCE(hours_worked,0)hours_worked 
   from users 
   left join records on  users.id = records.users_id and date_worked = '2012-12-18'
   where active_pilot = 1 
   order by date_worked asc 
   </cfquery>
   <cfloop query="test">
    ['#test.name[test.currentrow]#', #test.hours_works[test.currentrow]#]<cfif not thefinaloutput>,</cfif>
   </cfloop>        
 </cfloop>
]);
```

Comment: Everything is working great now. Thank you so much Matt and Peter :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your example you are only plotting one data point for each person, therefore no line is seen.  I took your source output and modified it to show a line. You will just need to get your output to mimic this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <h1>Pilot Timesheet</h1>
            <a href="excel_sheet_downloader.cfm"><button class="btn"       type="button" name="download_pilot_report">Download</button></a>
      <br />
      <br />
    <h1>Grapher</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
                    ['Date Worked', 'Keegan', 'Brady', 'Isaac', 'Christoph', 'Tyler'],

                        ['2012-12-18', 0.0,0.0,0.0,5.5,0.0],
                        ['2012-12-18', 0.0,0.0,0.0,4.5,0.0],
                        ['2012-12-18', 0.0,0.0,0.0,3.5,0.0],
                        ['2012-12-18', 0.0,0.0,0.0,2.5,0.0]

                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Test'
                };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be an issue with comma placement - you'll be getting `['Date Worked','a','b',],[...][...][...]` instead of the desired `['Date Worked','a','b'],[...],[...],[...]`

To fix that, try changing your `var data` section to this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable ([
    ['Date Worked' <cfloop query="name">, '#name#'</cfloop>]
    <cfloop from="2012-12-18" to="2012-12-18" index="i">
        <!--- query removed for readability --->
        , ['#test.date_worked#', #Valuelist(test.hours_worked)#]
    </cfloop>
]);
```

i.e. placing the commas as the first output for both loops, after the first elements.

You may also need to look at using JsStringFormat function to ensure the database output is correctly encoded (particularly for `name` variable).

Comment: The commas are placing in the right order now thank you. Lines still do not display so I am going to look into the JsStringFormat function. Thank you again!

Comment: JsStringFormat will fix things like `O'Reilly` etc - your view source doesn't appear to have those, so may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have ColdFusion tags inside javascript.  Since ColdFusion runs on the server and javascript runs on the client that's pretty much always a bad plan.

Comment: The intent here appears to be to generate JS data (rather than execute CF logic on the client-side), so it's perfectly valid to have the CFML code where it is.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion to grab the data off a database on the server. I do not believe this is the issue. I have a feeling the issue is that I'm not setting names to their values that are getting graphed. I am a little lost on how that syntax would look.